# I've got a working boolean function, but my code is very clumsy. How can I make it smoother?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, boolean, logic

The problem goes as following:

> You are driving a little too fast, and a police officer stops you.
> Write code to compute the result, encoded as an int value: 0=no
> ticket, 1=small ticket, 2=big ticket. If `speed` is 60 or less, the
> result is 0. If `speed` is between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is 1.
> If `speed` is 81 or more, the result is 2. Unless it `is_birthday` --
> on that day, your speed can be 5 higher in all cases.

And my function goes as following:

```
def caught_speeding(speed, is_birthday):
  if is_birthday:
    if speed <= 65:
      return 0
    if 66 <= speed <= 86:
      return 1
    if speed >= 86:
      return 2
  if not is_birthday:
    if speed <= 60:
      return 0
    if 61 <= speed <= 81:
      return 1
    if speed >= 81:
      return 2
```

Comment: That's not clumsy.  I suppose you could reduce the size slightly by saying `if is_birthday: speed -= 5` and then use the non-birthday sequence.

Comment: You could stop checking unnecessary conditions: e.g. after establishing that the speed is greater than 65, you don't need to check it in the next if statement.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I believe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit for your question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This would be my first attempt. You can just remove the `if not is_birthday` after you return on every other branch.

```py
def caught_speeding(speed: int, is_birthday: bool) -> int:

  if is_birthday:
    if speed <= 65:
      return 0
    elif speed <= 86:
      return 1
    else:
      return 2

  if speed <= 60:
    return 0
  elif speed <= 81:
    return 1
  else:
    return 2
```

Comment: It can be simplified even further - `elif 66 <= speed <= 86` -> `elif speed <= 86` and `elif 61 <= speed <= 81` -> `elif speed <= 81`